# The scrolling behavior does not move up Ionic Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

Ionic 6, Vuejs 3

```
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
    routes,
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
        return savedPosition || { top: 0 }
    },
})
```

Or

```
scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
        if (savedPosition && to.meta.keepAlive) {
            return savedPosition;
        }

        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve({ x: 0, y: 0 });
            }, 5);
        });
    },
```

The position of the window does not change, it remains at the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
updated() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        document.querySelector('ion-content').scrollToTop(500);
    });
},
```